# Makefile generating error

Tags: c, makefile

Every time I enter the command on UNIX

```
unix1% make clean
```

It returns an error message

```
mksh: Warning: newline is not last character in file makefile
Current working directory /home/s/m/mel
rm -f *.o core firstpass 
unix1%
```

Here is my makefile:

```
firstpass: main.o hashFunct.o symbolTable.o opcodeTable.o 
        gcc main.o hashFunct.o symbolTable.o opcodeTable.o -o firstpass

main.o: main.c
        gcc -c main.c

hashFunct.o: hashFunct.c
        gcc -c hashFunct.c

symbolTable.o: symbolTable.c
        gcc -c symbolTable.c

opcodeTable.o: opcodeTable.c
        gcc -c opcodeTable.c

clean:
       rm -f *.o core firstpass
```

I don't understand the problem, and I've tried to open it in emacs and see no mysterious characters. Also the word firstpass is the last character in the makefile. What does this error exactly mean?

Answer (score 4):

> *mksh: Warning: newline is not last character in file makefile*

The problem is exactly what it said, it wants a newline as the last character of the file. Currently the last character is probably the `s` of `firstpass`.

Open it in an editor, go to the end of the file, hit return.

Some editors will add a final newline to files for you.

A newline at the end of a file should not be a requirement. This sort of warning is common in older systems whose parsers might freak out if they are given input without a newline. Perl 1 is the only time I've seen this in the wild, and that's from 1987, but C compilers still issue this warning.

Comment: FWIW, C compilers issue such warnings because according to the international standard, the source code of a C program *must* end with a newline.  Whether that's a sensible requirement -- for C or for anything else -- is a different question.